# Cannot start Cassandra, getting "Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [seeds] from your cassandra.yaml"

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

```
# tail /var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt (JI)[B
INFO  [main] 2022-08-22 09:52:55,359 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:93 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [seeds] from your cassandra.yaml
Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [seeds] from your cassandra.yaml
ERROR [main] 2022-08-22 09:52:55,634 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [seeds] from your cassandra.yaml
[root@xxxx yum.repos.d]#
```

Comment: Aug 22 10:18:27 qlg72 cassandra[70630]: Starting Cassandra: OK
Aug 22 10:18:27 qlg72 systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
Aug 22 10:18:30 qlg72 systemd[1]: cassandra.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Aug 22 10:18:30 qlg72 systemd[1]: cassandra.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
#

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am unable t start cassandra services in my 4 servers. there is some issue with yml file configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you have a misconfiguration in the `cassandra.yaml`.

It looks like you've added the seeds incorrectly. In YAML files, indentation is important because it is how "nesting" is implied.

The correct format for configuring seeds is:

```
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "ip1,ip2,..."
```

Fix your configuration then try to restart again. Cheers!

**[UPDATE]** Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra) (part of the Stack Overflow network of sites but dedicated to DBAs instead of developers). Cheers!

Comment: But getting bellow error   tail/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log      
ERROR [main] 2022-08-23 05:57:14,599 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 Error: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 6, column 17:
          parameters: "seeds,listen_address,rpc_address"

Comment: seed_provider:
       -  class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
           parameters: "seeds,listen_address,rpc_address"
          - seeds: "IP1,1IP2,IP3,IP4"
          - listen_address: “IP1,1IP2,IP3,IP4”
          - rpc_address: “IP1,1IP2,IP3,IP4”........
                    ^

Comment: You've completely misconfigured your nodes. The `listen_address` and `rpc_address` parameters do not belong to `seed_provider`. Use a fresh copy of `cassandra.yaml` as a template and start again. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick for your guidance, it was done. Also one last question from my end, is there any specific limitations  on using the minimum number host for Cassandra installation Eg. like whether we can only use one host for installing cassandra and YCSB both?

Comment: That's a completely different question that's unrelated to your original question so please post a new one. Otherwise, the comments section will be a never-ending thread of follow up questions. Cheers!